# Illusion of Choice in Circular Table Arrangement Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $n$ (with $n \geq 3$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$) tables in a room with a circular arrangement (each table is connected to exactly two other tables). You, your friend (will later be referenced as they/them), and others (whom you don't care) will be seated on a table. Each one will sit on one table, so there are a total of $n$ people. You want to sit beside them.

There are two scenarios of the problem:

(1) You initially pick a seat—your position is determined from the start. Then, you can choose between them or others one by one to pick a seat randomly with a uniform distribution.

(2) The seats are randomized at once for all people with uniform distribution.

I conjectured that in the first scenario, there exist a sequence of choices of them or others, so that the probability of you sitting beside them increases. In other words, the first scenario will increase the probability if the correct choices are made.

Now, my questions are as follows.

(1) What is the probability that you sit next to them for $n$ tables in the second scenario?

(2) Is my conjecture right?

(3) If it was right, how can we find the optimum sequence of choices?

(4) If it was right, how much does the probability increase from the second scenario?

After tinkering for some amount of time, it looks like that there is no difference of the probability in both scenarios. Yet, I feel that I can sit next to them with much higher probability.

(5) If the conjecture was wrong, why do I feel like I have more control?

For the first question, I found $\frac{2}{n-1}$ as the answer. However, I can't prove it formally. I tried to use induction, but I'm stuck after the induction hypothesis step.

Comment: If I understand you right, there's no difference between the two scenarios.  If everyone is seated uniformly at random all at once, you still have to sit somewhere.  After that, the two scenarios are identical.

Comment: @saulspatz In the first scenario, you can choose either them or the other one by one, not all at once.

Comment: So long as you're choosing uniformly at random, it doesn't matter if you choose them all at once or one-by-one.  Every permutation has the same probability.

Comment: @saulspatz Hmm, interesting. Can you please show me how? And maybe show me the common mathematical reasoning or psychological error that I have made? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If there $n$ tables, let $p=p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$ be a permutation of the integers from $1$ to $n$.  In the context of the problem, we take $p$ to represent the to represent the case where person $k$ sits at table $p_k$, for $k=1,2,\dots,n$.

Since there are $n!$ possible such permutations, if we choose a permutation uniformly at random, the probability of choosing $p$ is $\frac1{n!}$.  What is the probability of getting $p$ if we seat the people one by one, choosing uniformly at random at each step?  The probability that we seat person $1$ at table $p_1$ is $\frac1n$.  Then the probability that we seat person $2$ at table $p_2$ is $\frac1{n-1}$ because table $P_1$ is already taken.  If we let $X_k$ be the random variable that gives the number of the table at which person $k$ is seated, then $$\Pr(X_1=p_1\land X_2=p_2)=\Pr(X_1=p_1)\Pr(X_2=p_2\mid X_1 = p_1)=\frac1n\frac1{n-1}$$
Now, once persons $1$ and $2$ have been seated, the probability that person $3$ is seated at table $3$ is $\frac1{n-2}$ and as above the probability that all three events occurs is $$\frac1n\frac1{n-1}\frac1{n-2}$$

We can continue this line of reasoning through all $n$ people to get to the answer $\frac1{n!}$.  Or if you like, you can easily prove it by induction.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question. I don't want to find the probability of a single permutation (that's trivial). I want to find the probability of me sitting next to my friend. And given that the arrangements are circular, table 1 is next to table 2 and also table $n$. I'm going to draw a graph for this question if it helps.

Comment: @Faris I was answering the question in your comment, about why choosing all at once or sequentially is inconsequential.  Once you accept that, your question is easy.  Obviously, if the the probability of any permutation is identical either way, then the probability of any event is also identical, since an event is just a set of permuatations.

Comment: Ah, okay. So you only have proven that it does not matter if the sampling is all at once or one by one.

Comment: @Faris Yes, because it means that there is really only one scenario.  Your answer of $\frac2{n-1}$ is correct for one of them, so it's correct for both.